# HTML, <table> background

Tags: html, css

I've got one problem...

I created table(with one row and one column) for my site and then I put background for `table` using `CSS` where I defined image, after that I try to create in the first table another table with 3 rows, Dreamweaver doesn't allow me to do it, it puts new table after first, how can I solve this problem, thanks in advance...

```
<table width="1158" height="1193" border="0" align="center" class="img_fixed">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <table width="1000" border="0">
            <tr>
                <th width="1152" height="1189" scope="col"><div align="center"></div></th>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
             </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


</table>
```

Comment: please put code u write so far?

Comment: Try to type codes like this into Dreamweaver, its automatic tabling tools aren't for doing such things as this. Also when asking questions it would be helpful to post some relevant HTML and CSS codes for us to see :)

Comment: Don't do that. http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

Comment: I'ms sorry, but what did You mean? It is not good to use table layout for website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is worked properly what is your problem?  I posted the example for that code

```
<table width="100%" height="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-image:url(book1.png)">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

lego your code must be like this,

```
<table width="1158" height="1193" border="0" align="center" class="img_fixed">  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="1000" border="0">
        <tr>  
          <th width="1152" height="1189" scope="col"><div align="center"></div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>  <td>&nbsp;</td>  </tr> 
        <tr>  <td>&nbsp;</td>  </tr>  
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```